# How to send a DM to a specific member with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a bot using discord.js with a function where I would like to send a message to a specific member.

How can I do to send a message to a specific member (with identification code such as "346176733549953029") rather than using message.author.send("the text I want to send") which send a message to the person who type the command?

I would need something like :

```
message.user.get("346176733549953029").send("test I want to send");
```

The final should be for that member to receive a private message from the bot with the message inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve a user by their ID from the client's cache of users, [`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users). However, every user isn't guaranteed to be cached at all times, so you can fetch a user from Discord using [`Client.fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser). Keep in mind, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You can send a user a message using [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) (or [`GuildMember.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send)).

Putting it together...

```js
// Async context needed for 'await' keyword.
// Assuming 'client' is the instance of your Discord Client.

try {
  // Retrieve the user from the client's cache.
  // If they haven't been cached yet, fetch them.
  const userID = '189855563893571595';
  const user = client.users.get(userID) || await client.fetchUser(userID);

  // Send the user a DM.
  await user.send('Hello.');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Note that due to a user's specific privacy settings, DMs may not be able to be sent. In this case, you need to catch the rejected promise.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, once again you found the solution :)